# Is it possible to influence GCC/Clang/Intel ICPC XMM/YMM register allocation?

Tags: gcc, assembly, clang, intrinsics, icc

I have a highly optimized function called repeatedly in the inner loop, written with SSE2/AVX2 accelerations. After some refinement, now I am approaching the theoretical best performance (based on instruction latency and throughput). However, the performance is not quite portable. The problem lies in that there are more than 16 `__m128i`/`__256i` variables. Of course, only 16 of them can be allocated in registers, and the remaining on stack. The function is more or less like the following,

```
void eval(size_t n, __m128i *rk /* other inputs */)
{
    __m128i xmmk0 = rk[0];
    // ...
    __m128i xmmk6 = rk[6];
    __m128i xmmk;

    __m128i xmmk[Rounds - 6];
    // copy rk[7] to r[Rounds] to xmmk

    while (n >= 8) {
        n -= 8;

        __m128i xmm0 = /* initialize state xmm0 */
        // do the same for xmm1 - xmm7

        // round 0
        xmm0 = /* a few instructions involving xmm0 and xmmk0 */;
        // do the same for xmm1 - xmm7

        // do the same for round 1 to 6, using xmmk1, ..., xmmk6

        // round 7, copy xmmk[0] to a temporary __m128i variable
        xmm0 = /* a few instructions involving xmm0 and xmmk[0] */;
        // do the same for xmm1 - xmm7

        // do the same for round 7 to Rounds, using xmmk[1], xmmk[Rounds - 7]
    }
}
```

There are more than 16 `__m128i` variables involved. The best performance I can get is when the compiler allocate `xmm0` to `xmm7`, the states, `xmmk0` to `xmmk6`, the first 7 round constants, in registers, and use the remaining register as a temporary that load round constants for the remaining rounds. When written in a way similar to the above, GCC/clang are doing exactly that, but Intel ICPC allocate some of the `xmm0` to `xmm7` variables on stack and introduce some unnecessary memory movement. If instead, I write in a way similar to the following

```
__m128i xmmk[Rounds + 1]; // copy from input rk
// let compiler to figure out which of them are allocated on stack and which in registers,
```

Then GCC/ICPC are doing a good job of register allocation while clang fall into a situation similar to that of ICPC in previous case.

Of course, declaring a variable of type `__m128i` does not make it an register, nor does declaring it in a stack array prevent the compiler to allocate register for it.

I was able to write an ASM implementation which does exactly what I want. However, the actual function involves some compile time constants specified as template policies. So it is more desirable to implement them in C++ with intrinsics.

What I want to know is if there's a way to influence how these compilers perform register allocation. Usually the difference in performance is merely a few cycles, because of fast L1 cache. However, when highly optimized, when the inner loop takes only a hundred cycles, a dozen cycle difference due to unnecessary memory movement translate to a 20% overall performance difference. As far as I know, there's no way to make compilers doing things exactly as in hand written assembly. But it would be a lot helpful if I can at least give them some hints. For example, I know that latency of loading the round constants can be hidden by other instructions. And thus it is more desirable to allocate them on stack instead of the state variable `xmm0` to `xmm7`.

Comment: Have you tried the `register` keyword? :) Yeah that's only a hint and the compiler may ignore it.

Comment: @Jester That's the first thing I tried. I haven't used that keyword in years. But it does not work at all, just as expected. In fact, this `register` will be removed in C++1z as far as I know

Comment: If the addresses are constant, it's maybe no so much the latency (which OOO hides) but just the extra uops.  You might even try stuff like `register __m128i foo asm("xmm0");`.  That GNU extension forces the compiler to use that register for that variable throughout the function, which might actually make things worse by requiring a MOVDQA to put the result back there after a non-commutative operation would more naturally end up with the current value of the variable in a different register.  I just tried, it doesn't seem to defeat the optimizer in simple cases: (https://godbolt.org/g/C6THwl).

Comment: @YanZhou It might be useful to tag either C or C++ depending on what language you program in.

Comment: Yeah, many more people look at the `[c]` tag than `[gcc]` or `[assembly]`.  I'd probably drop the "intrinsics" tag.